# Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: Not a directory (needed by ./bin/busybox

Tags: c, arm, qemu, lib, busybox

I want to run a busybox with `qemu-arm-static` 
`file busybox` is output:

```
bin/busybox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-arm.so.1, corrupted section header size
```

And when I use `qemu-arm-static` to run it ,I get output:

```
sudo chroot ./ ./qemu-arm-static --strace -E LD_PRELOAD="./lib/libgcc_s.so.1 ./lib/libc.so" ./bin/busybox

8703 set_tid_address(-159394608,-150997504,1,-159391584,-159394636,-159391584) = 8703
8703 open("./lib/libgcc_s.so.1",O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
8703 fcntl64(3,F_SETFD,1) = 0
8703 fstat64(3,0xf6fff298) = 0
8703 read(3,0xf6ffee98,936) = 936
8703 mmap2(NULL,110592,PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,3,0) = 0xf6763000
8703 mmap2(0xf677d000,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED,3,0xa) = 0xf677d000
8703 close(3) = 0
8703 open("./lib/libc.so",O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
8703 fcntl64(3,F_SETFD,1) = 0
8703 fstat64(3,0xf6fff298) = 0
8703 read(3,0xf6ffee98,936) = 936
8703 mmap2(NULL,528384,PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE,3,0) = 0xf66e2000
8703 mmap2(0xf675f000,16384,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED,3,0x6d) = 0xf675f000
8703 mmap2(0xf6761000,8192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_FIXED,-1,0) = 0xf6761000
8703 close(3) = 0
8703 open("/etc/ld-musl-arm.path",O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
8703 fcntl64(3,F_SETFD,1) = 0
8703 fcntl64(3,F_SETFD,1) = 0
8703 readv(3,-150998608,2,1024,-159920112,1) = 22
8703 readv(3,-150998608,2,1024,-159920112,1) = 0
8703 close(3) = 0
8703 open("/lib/ld-musl-arm.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1",O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 errno=20 (Not a directory)
8703 writev(2,0xf6fff0a8,0x2)Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: Not a directory (needed by ./bin/busybox = 84
8703 writev(2,0xf6fff3a0,0x2)) = 1
8703 writev(2,0xf6fff388,0x2)
 = 1
8703 mprotect(0xf675f000,4096,PROT_READ) = 0
8703 mprotect(0xf67fb000,4096,PROT_READ) = 0
8703 exit_group(127)
```

There are some information I also get

```
command: readelf -d bin/busybox | grep NEEDED
output:  
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     shared library：[libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     shared library：[libc.so]

command: file lib/ld-musl-arm.so.1
output: lib/ld-musl-arm.so.1: symbolic link to libc.so
```

so, I want to know what's wrong with it,and how can I run the busybox successfully,thanks!

I want to know what's wrong with it,and how can I run the busybox successfully,thanks!

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Do you have source to anything?  Are you building it?  The libraries don't match.  You can not just expect qemu to run arbitrary code.  You need the filesystems to match.  Ie, the busybox build file system needs to match qeum.

Comment: Yes, and also you need to either chroot into the guest file system directory or else tell QEMU the path to it using the -L option or equivalent environment variable. If you do that you shouldn't need to use LD_PRELOAD like that (which looks to me like a workaround for the fact you haven't told QEMU where the guest file system is).